# Save and restore UINavigation stacks to reconnect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, save, restore

I am currently having a hard time understanding what I should use to save and restore my app state.

I am using a storyboard and I have quite some ViewControllers, and I want to save all my navigation stacks when the app is terminated to be able to restore all the navigation when the user relaunch the application.

I am using a `UINavigationController` with another UINavigationController inside it just for information.

I found this and read this over and over :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH28-SW34

> (Required) Assign restoration identifiers to the view controllers whose configuration you want to preserve; see Tagging View Controllers for Preservation.
>
> (Required) Tell iOS how to create or locate new view controller objects at launch time; see Restoring View Controllers at Launch Time.

Then I added a `RestorationId` on all my ViewControllers but I don't understand what I should do for the second part as when I add `viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath` methods I don't pass inside.

I also tried to save the `navigation.viewcontrollers` into the NSUserDefaults in order to use them again when the user restart the app
using the code :

```
+(NSArray *) getNavStatus
{
    NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id objectSaved;
    if( (objectSaved = [preferences objectForKey:navStatusKey]) != nil)
        return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:objectSaved];
    else
        return nil;
}

+(BOOL) saveNavStatus:(UINavigationController *) nav
{
    NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:nav.viewControllers];
    [preferences setObject:encodedObject forKey:navStatusKey];
    
    //  Save to disk
    return [preferences synchronize];
}
```

But when I get back in the app apple stats to tell me that the constraint ain't respected and that the app will crash and then when I add the viewControllers in the stack of my navigation it does crash :)

Any tips or help would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you implement `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`? You can also check this tutorial. It will help you. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_6_iPhone_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial

Comment: I did now I can get some restoration, but as I said I want to do the same process after killing the application myself, but when the user kill it, the restoration isn't launched at next starts, so is there a way to force it ?

Comment: as per above restore viewControllers state its won't work while you relaunch application from stretch. Apple's default restore navigation state will not work in this case but you can do same with save this user state in DB and while app is opening at that time restore it by manually programming logic other than there is no solution of above problem, But this logic is only work with 3-4 navigation push if you have 7-8 navigation push than it will not work.

Comment: I actually tried using the `NSUserDefaults` as I said but when I put the navigationView saved I just get rejected ^^ and the app crash. Mine use quite much push ( around 15 I think)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you implement `application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:` and `application: shouldSaveApplicationState:`  methods in application delegate. Hope the step blow can help you:

**1. Set restoration identifiers**

When assigning restoration identifiers, remember that all parent view controllers in the view controller hierarchy must have restoration identifiers too. Also include NavigationController and TabBar…

> - a. Assign a valid string to the view’s restorationIdentifier    property.
> - b. Use the view from a view controller that also has a valid    restoration identifier.
> - c. For table views and collection views, assign a data source that    adopts the UIDataSourceModelAssociation protocol.
>
> -

**2. Tell application you want use State Preservation**

Add  the two methods to the application delegate.m  file to required both saving and restoration of application state

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

**3. Write and read Controller state**

You  Preservation  Controller must adopt the UIStateRestoring protocol and use the methods of that protocol to write and read its state.

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        if (_textLabel.text.length > 0) {
            [coder encodeObject:_textLabel.text forKey:@"labelText"];
        }
        [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    }

    -(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        _textLabel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"labelText"];
        [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    }
```

**4. Restore ViewController**

Implement viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder: method of the associated restoration class to retrieve the view controller.

```
+ (nullable UIViewController *)viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents coder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    ViewControllerThree * restoreVc;
    UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [coder decodeObjectForKey:UIStateRestorationViewControllerStoryboardKey];
    if (storyBoard) {
        restoreVc = (ViewControllerThree*)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerThree"];
        restoreVc.restorationIdentifier = [identifierComponents lastObject];
        restoreVc.restorationClass = [ViewControllerThree class];
    }
    return restoreVc;
}
```

Comment: This is actually quite useful but it only answer half my question. Cause I can only use this to restore from background app that have been killed. But I want my app to do the same after I killed it. Is there a way to launch the restoration process programmaticaly ?

Comment: You cannot kill the app yourself via the app switcher, otherwise state restoration simply won’t work.

Comment: where will we implement this method ? i each view controller  ? 
viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder